# re python - Capture space or non-alphabet characters in a string before a : symbol

Tags: python, regex

I would like to split the string before a `:` symbol, even when there rea spaces or weird punctuation before the symbol appears as well. For example, I'd like the string:

`De'Angelo: hey everyone. Alexander the Great: wait. Alexander the Great: this is a weird script. Mark:))): Hello.`

to return...

`['De'Angelo', 'hey everyone.', 'Alexander the Great', 'wait.', 'Alexander the Great', 'this is a weird script.', 'Mark:)))', 'Hello.']`

Comment: Why does no split occur at `Mark:)))`?  Can you better explain your logic?

Comment: In the application I'm working on, the user is allowed to use any name he or she wants. I've seen people use something like this unfortunately. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: OK, but you didn't actually answer my question.

Comment: In this case, `Mark:)))` is a username a user gave himself, so I didn't think about splitting it up. I don't know how else to explain myself. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of a positive lookbehind and a split on `':'`:

```
import re
s = "De'Angelo: hey everyone. Alexander the Great: wait. Alexander the Great: this is a weird script. Mark:))): Hello."
new_s = re.split(':\s|(?<=\W)\s', s)
```

Output:

```
["De'Angelo", 'hey everyone.', 'Alexander the Great', 'wait.', 'Alexander the Great', 'this is a weird script.', 'Mark:)))', 'Hello.']
```